# why Href attribute can't redirect to the respective js file?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

why my button is not redirecting to the respective .js file?

Basically i am using Button with href tage where href="signup.js" and signup.js file is present in my project.

Can we use href tag to link a ".js" file properly and redirect properly...
Button has been imported from react-bootstrap so what changes should be madeso user click on Button and go to signup.js file?

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Typography from '../components/Typography';
import ProductHeroLayout from './ProductHeroLayout';
    
const backgroundImage =
    'https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/female-boss-online-conference-meeting-woman-crossed-hands-office-desk-front-laptop-student-teaches-exam-139215819.jpg';
    
const styles = (theme) => ({
    background: {
    backgroundImage: `url(${backgroundImage})`,
    backgroundColor: '#7fc7d9', // Average color of the background image.
    backgroundPosition: 'center',
    },
    button: {
    minWidth: 200,
    },
    h5: {
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(4),
    marginTop: theme.spacing(4),
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
        marginTop: theme.spacing(10),
    },
    },
    more: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
    },
});
    
function ProductHero(props) {
    const { classes } = props;
    
    return (
    <ProductHeroLayout backgroundClassName={classes.background}>
        {/* Increase the network loading priority of the background image. */}
        <img style={{ display: 'none' }} src={backgroundImage} alt="increase priority" />
        <Typography color="inherit" align="center" variant="h2" marked="center">
        Upgrade your knowledge
        </Typography>
        <Typography color="inherit" align="center" variant="h5" className={classes.h5}>
        Test Your Skills.
        </Typography>
        <Button
        color="secondary"
        variant="contained"
        size="large"
        className={classes.button}
        component="a"
        href="SignUp.js"
        >
        User Registeration
        </Button>
        <Typography variant="body2" color="inherit" className={classes.more}>
        Be Digital
        </Typography>
    </ProductHeroLayout>
    );
}
    
ProductHero.propTypes = {
    classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
    
export default withStyles(styles)(ProductHero);
```

Comment: We have no idea what your `Button` component (and since it has a capital letter at the start, it is a React component and not an HTML button element) does, so we can't tell you. You need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: This looks like a Material UI component.  What is the resulting rendered element?  How specifically does it fail?

Comment: Your question is still unclear. What actually happens when the button is clicked on? Does the URL in the address bar change? Does the request for the JS file show up in the console? Is the server configured to serve the JS file at all (it seems unlikely that any system using React would have a relative URL to a JS file in the current path actually resolve to a JS file). Why are you trying to link to a JS file anyway? Are you really trying to show JS source code to the user?